# Can Cloud Vision API detect dimensions of an object?

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I am exploring features of Cloud Vision API and I was wondering if there is any way to detect dimensions of an object under label detection. For example, if you take a picture of a car on street, then Cloud Vision API would return dimensions of the car (length, height or width)

Answer (score 3):

LABEL_DETECTION will return an EntityAnnotation. For the field boundingPoly the documentation states: "Image region to which this entity belongs. Not filled currently for LABEL_DETECTION features."

So no, no at the moment it does not return dimensions. This is the related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35737830/can-i-receive-a-boudingpoly-for-label-detection-results).

Just to be clear it would always return dimensions in image space i.e. pixel coordinates, never in object space, i.e. physical dimensions of the object.